# EXC_BAD_ACCESS When Trying to Perform a strcat Function in C

Tags: c, unix

I have a program I am writing for uni in C, and when my code reaches this line:

```
strcat("md5 ", "blah");
```

I am getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error, and my app crashes.  As far as I can tell, there isn't anything wrong with it, so I thought a fresh pair of eyes might solve my problem.  Any ideas?

Comment: try enabling warnings for you compiler.

Comment: Warnings can be enabled with `-Wall` if you're using GCC. Unfortunately, it doesn't warn against this error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to modify a constant string. The first argument of `strcat` is also the destination string and in your case it is a constant string. You should use something like:

```
char s[100];
strcpy(s, "md5 ");
strcat(s, "blah");
```

Answer (score 3):

In C, you have to provide the space of where to store something yourself. "md5 " has only room for 4 characters (+ a nul terminator). There is not enough space to append "blah" there.

More important, you cannot modify a string literal. They are usually read only.
So, you have to:

- Provide storage where you can store the new, concatenated result.
- Makes sure there's enough room in that storage for the resulting string.

E.g.:

```
char result[9]; //the result here needs 8 characters + a nul terminator
strcpy(result,"md5 ");
strcat(result,"blah"
```

Or, e.g.

```
const char *a = "md5 ";
const char *b = "blah";
char *result = malloc(strlen(a) + strlen(b) + 1);
if(result == NULL) {
  out of memory
  return;
}
strcpy(result,a);
strcat(result,b);
```

Comment: Actually, it's not really about free space. It's about constant strings being placed in a read-only memory page in this implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The first string supplied to strcat needs to be a *writable* buffer with enough space for the second string *past its current contents*. That means that you *cannot* use string literals as the first argument for strcat()!

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat/ :

Appends a copy of the source string to the destination string. The terminating null character in destination is overwritten by the first character of source, and a new null-character is appended at the end of the new string formed by the concatenation of both in destination.

Since your first string is a constant, you don't know where it is in memory and you aren't allowed to play with the memory that follows it.